# What happens when you run a python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter

I'm just trying to get an understanding of compilers and interpreters with python. I don't fully get it yet so I might use some terms incorrectly.

My understanding right now:

1. CPython is both the compiler (to bytecode) for python as well as a vm where that bytecode is interpreted and run as machine code
2. so when you run a .py file CPython compiles your code into bytecode.
3. that bytecode is then converted to machine code in the python vm (which is also cpython?)

Comment: The byte code *may* be converted to machine code. That's what a just-in-time (JIT) compiler does. CPython strictly *interprets* each byte code; that's why it's a VM, not a compiler.

Comment: @chepner ok so you're saying CPython does not compile to bytecode, just interprets it. What compiles your code to bytecode then?

Comment: No, CPython compiles Python source code to byte code, then interprets the byte code. CPython doesn't translate anything into machine code.

Comment: @chepner ooh ok, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @chepner I have another question. Is the reason (or atleast part of the reason) that python is slower than a language like c because the compiling to bytecode and interpreting the bytecode happens during runtime? while in c the code is compiled to machine code AND THEN that machine code is all run by ur cpu during runtime. also is bytecode interpreted one instruction at a time?

Comment: @skushu The fact that the bytecode compilation happens at runtime makes little difference compared to other factors. Python does cache the bytecode of modules (that is, if you run the same application multiple times without changing the source code, subsequent runs will only only recompile the main file) and there are ways to precompile all files. But all of that only affects start up time, which usually doesn't have a significant impact on the overall runtime of the code.

Comment: The fact that CPython is a pure interpreter does make a significant difference. Alternative implementations of Python that feature JIT compilation exist and do achieve notable performance improvements in many cases (though not to the extent that performance becomes comparable to C). Note that JIT compilation still happens at runtime, so this is more of a compilation vs. interpretation thing than runtime vs. compile time. I do not believe that an ahead-of-time compiler for Python would yield better results than a JIT compiler. In fact they'd probably be worse.

Comment: The reason for that are language features of Python that don't lend themselves well to ahead-of-time compilation or efficient implementation in general. These include dynamic typing and meta programming and generally the dynamic nature of Python. When it comes to language features that are challenging to implement efficiently (though not necessarily hard to compile), that would also include things like the default integer type being arbitrary precision and of course garbage collection.